# Show / Hide tr after image with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="tbl">
     <tr><th>My Table</th></tr>
     <tr><td><div class="arrow"></div></td></tr>
     <tr><td>The second row</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to show / hide the `tr` after arrow. I have written this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tbl tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#tbl tr:even").addClass("even");
    $("#tbl tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#tbl tr:first-child").show();
    $('.arrow').click(function () {
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("up");
    });
});
```

but this cant show or hide tr. How can I solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parents("tr:first")` to walk up  the chain and select the parent `tr` of the div then it should work.  It should be noted that there are some selector optimizations you might want to make for your other calls/setup.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tbl tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#tbl tr:even").addClass("even");
    $("#tbl tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#tbl tr:first-child").show();
    $('.arrow').click(function(){
      $(this).parents("tr:first").next("tr").toggle();
      $(this).toggleClass("up");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you put in a call to closest() before next(), you'll get the TR for the arrow, and then next() will select the row after that.

```
$(this).closest("tr").next().toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

This'll do it,  i stripped out your hiding and showing code cos it was making all the rows not display in the first place.

what you need to do is get the closes tr from your arrow div, then get the next one from that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tbl tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#tbl tr:even").addClass("even");

    $('.arrow').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("up");
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SLc5d/